# Retrieve a similar query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

In a nutshell, this page populates a course, and at the bottom I have three boxes for similar courses, and where the similar course cannot be the current course refered by as Id. They are similar in terms of course_title.

Below is how the current course is populated:

```
  $get_crs_similar = "select * from courses where course_id='$course_id'";
```

I would like to retrieve three similar course, where I am thinking I would retrieve the last similar course for first 1, and then the second last similar course, and then the third similar course, where all 3 cannot be equal to the current course.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Html
    
        Similar Courses

```
        <div class="well-none">

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <div class="item active">

                          <div class="row">
                          <h4>  <?php echo $crs_title2; ?></h4>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="coursePage.php?crs_id=4656" class="thumbnail"><img src="content/negotiation.png" alt="Image" width="250" height="250" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                                                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="content/azure2.png" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="content/server.png"  alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="content/azure3.png"  alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Similar in what way?

Comment: similar by course_title, sorry i forgot to mention that. course_title is a varible

Comment: which criteria says when a course is similar to another? (already asked, didn t refresh the page)

Comment: perhaps: `where course_title like %xxxx%`

Answer (score 1):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM courses AS c1
JOIN courses AS c2 ON c1.course_title = c2.course_title AND c1.course_id != c2.course_id
WHERE c2.course_id = $course_id
LIMIT 3
```

This will return 3 courses that have the same title as the given course, but are not the same course.

Comment: thanks for response. How would I populate it. I've updated my code with the html

Comment: The same way you write the output of any other query to your web page. There are hundreds of tutorials that show how to create web pages from MySQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a separate query then simply get course title by using like..since course title is a variable, there is no need of self join.

select * from courses where course_id != '$course_id' and course_title like '%***%'

Comment: thanks for response. How would I populate it. I've updated my code with the html